# What happens if the namenode and the ZooKeeper fail together

Tags: hadoop, failover, apache-zookeeper

What happens if the namenode and the ZooKeeper fail together. is this possible? Also, do various QJM keep log edits of each other?

Answer (score 1):

If the Zookeeper server is installed on other nodes(not on namenode). It brings the other standby namenode to active state.

If you have installed more than 1 zookeeper server, for example consider you have installed 3 zookeeper servers. If one of the zookeeper fails, election process takes place and new zookeeper will be made active.

Answer (score 0):

A Zookeeper Quorum is used to avoid zookeeper failure. The Zookeeper replicates its data to other nodes in the quorum. In case of a failure? the election occurs and a new node is appointed the leader which directs the client to the secondary name node.